# How can I install ROS on a Mac using macports?

Tags: ros, homebrew, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am having problems to install ROS with Homebrew. Is there any possibility to install it using macports? The aim of my work is to use ROS to calibrate my Kinect and Mapping depth pixels with color pixels as it is explained in http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration#tocLink5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43527/how-can-i-install-ros-on-a-mac-using-macports?/) by [AndreBrandao](https://answers.ros.org/users/3183/andrebrandao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-09-10**:
Did you get the Kinect working under OSX? I seem to have problems with the OpenNI drivers personally. I tend to use the libfreenect ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well yes and no. There use to be a macports option, but no one maintained it. I personally find homebrew much easier to work with. If you want to ask for help on homebrew install, maybe we can get that going for you? Also, no mater if you use homebrew or macports, not everything (mainly the graphical tools) don't completely work on OSX right now. There is work underway to fix that, but it will be a while.

Good luck with whatever option you choose!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1